# Button to clear Treeview table in Tkinter not working?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I am making a simple program that takes stock from a website and shows them in  a Tkinter GUI based on what button the user presses. I want to create a button that lets them clear the table, so they can press on either 'Vapes' or 'Vape Juices' button to load up the stock of the items again after clearing them. I've tried the 'tree.delete(*tree.get_children()) method but the button doesn't do anything. I'm fairly new to treeview/Tkinter, any suggestions? Here is the code, thanks guys:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
def clear_table():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
def search_result():
    # fume infinity
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/fume-infinity-disposable-device")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
        # populate treeview
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
            tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Fume Extra
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/fume-extra-10pc")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
# populate treeview
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
            tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Fume ultra
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/fume-ultra-disposables")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
            # populate treeview
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # sea air plus
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/sea-air-plus-disposables")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Hyde Retro Recharge
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/hyde-retro-recharge-disposables")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Hyde rebel recharge
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/hyde-rebel-recharge-disposables")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Hyde recharge edge
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/hyde-recharge-edge-disposables")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 20:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Kangvape Onee Stick
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/kangvape-onee-stick-1900")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Kangvape Onee Stick Plus
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/kangvape-onee-plus-disposables")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Loy XL
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/loy-xl-disposables")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Bidi Sticks
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/disposable-vape-devices/bidi-sticks-disposables-6-salt-nic.html")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
                tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
def vape_juices():
    # Cloud Nurdz Juice
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/e-liquid/cloud-nurdz-iced-tobacco-free")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
        tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
    # Humble Co Juice
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/e-liquid/humble-e-liquids")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
        tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
        # twist premium juice
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/e-liquid/twist-premium-e-liquids-120-ml-bottles.html")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
        tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
        # bad drip juice
    driver.get("https://safagoods.com/vape-shop/e-liquid/bad-drip-60ml-bottles-freebase.html")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    table = wait.until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")))
    data = []
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".table.table-bordered tr[style='background: #eeeeee;']")
    for row in rows:
        qty = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").text
        stock = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").text
        name = row.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").text
        if int(stock) <= 50:
            data.append([stock, name])
    for idx, vals in enumerate(data):
        tree.insert(parent='', index=idx, values=vals)
#tkinter gui window and displayed options
window = Tk()
window.geometry("800x700")
search = Label(window,text= "Which stock would you like to check?",font='times 15')
search.place(x=275,y=20)
#buttons
b1 = Button(window,text="vapes",command=search_result,width = 12, bg= 'gray')
b1.place(x=150,y=50)
b2 = Button(window,text="Juices",command=vape_juices,width = 12, bg= 'gray')
b2.place(x=600,y=50)
b3 = Button(window,text="Clear Table",command =clear_table(), width = 12, bg='gray')
b3.place(x=400,y=50)

# add treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(window, selectmode = 'browse' )
tree['columns'] = ['Quantity', 'Flavor Name (Vape Brand/Juice Brand Name)']
tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tree.column('Quantity', anchor=CENTER, width=200)
tree.column('Flavor Name (Vape Brand/Juice Brand Name)', anchor=CENTER, width=300)
tree.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('Quantity', text='Quantity', anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('Flavor Name (Vape Brand/Juice Brand Name)', text='Flavor Name (Vape Brand/Juice Brand Name)   ', anchor=CENTER)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(window, orient ="vertical", command = tree.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side ='right', fill ='x')
tree.configure(xscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
tree.place(x=200, y=100)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command =clear_table()`?

Comment: Wow. I feel really dumb haha. Thanks for pointing this out. No wonder it wasn't working I had the parentheses on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from 8349697 pointed out that I left the () when calling the clear table function to my button 3 command. I removed the parentheses and it works.